# this.dragmove() interfering with mouseup event wpf

Tags: wpf, events, drag-and-drop

I have a UserControl in WPF.
The UserControl has a MouseLeftMouseButtonUp event.
The problem is- the Window has a this.DragMove() method in its MouseDown event which seems to interfere with the MouseLeftMouseButtonUp in the User Control (I need the this.DragMove() method to move the borderless window).
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific ? How exactly does it interfere ?

Comment: If I call the dragmove method in the Window's MouseDown event, then if I click on the user control- the MouseLeftButtonUp event doesn't fire. But if I don't call the dragmove method- the MouseLeftButtonUp event works fine.

Answer (score 7):

*DragMove* is a synchronous call; it blocks until the user is done moving the window.  This means once *DragMove* returns, **the left button is up**.  Add your code immediately after your *DragMove()* call and you should be fine.

Comment: But the DragMove call is in the Window_MouseDown event, and the code I want to run is in the UserControl_MouseLeftButtonUp event. How do I add the code after the DragMove so that it will only run when I click on the userControl?

Comment: When you click on the UserControl, you are initiating a MouseDown every time, even if you do not move the window.  DragMove returns after the mouse button has been released (MouseUp).  Does "only run when I click" really mean "only run when I do not move the window"?  If so, you could store the window position before and after calling DragMove.  If the window did not move, run your code.

Comment: Yes, but the MouseUp event doesn't get triggered at all.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem but found the answer. Your Window_MouseDown event will not run if the MouseDown has already been handled, so all you have to do to prevent DragMove from interfering with your control's mouse events is add this code:

```
Private Sub YourControl_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles YourControl.MouseDown
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   private void  MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      {
          e.Handled = true;
          if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
         {
            this.DragMove();
          }

          if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
          {
          //your mouse up code
          }
      }
```

Comment: Try to give a description about your answer , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I had issues like this too and found that using click events instead of mousebutton events kept from firing dragmove. For my fix I just had to swap a label for a button. It's possible you could subclass a different element for your usercontrol so that you could pick up a click event to use?